# Software for MPEG4 3DMC Mesh coding algorithm

Tags: graphics, mesh, mpeg-4

I was wondering where I may find a good C/C++ implementation of the 3DMC mesh coding algorithm which appears in the MPEG4 standard.

Thanks,
Debarati.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mymultimediaworld.com/

is the place,

SC3DMC is the exact standard, it features faster decoding than the older 3DMC standard.

The implementation works well in windows, in linux some tweeks are required,

Best,

Rufael